# Connecting windows 2012 to a linux ADDC, running samba 4 with ldap as backend

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, samba4, ubuntu-16.04

I have set up a Ubuntu server, running samba 4 and ldap, so it can act like a ADDC.

I have connected linux and mac machine though ldap, and windows server 2003-2008 machines through the samba domain. but a problem occurs when I'm trying to join a windows server 2012 machine to the samba domain.

when I'm trying to join the windows server, I get this error:

```
DNS was successfully queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate a domain controller for domain "MOSEK.INTRANET":
The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.MOSEK.INTRANET
The following domain controllers were identified by the query: fredericia.mosek.intranet

However no domain controllers could be contacted.
Common causes of this error include:
- Host (A) or (AAAA) records that map the names of the domain controllers to their IP addresses are missing or contain incorrect addresses.
- Domain controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or are not running.
so the server is asking the NDS correctly. The DNS returns the correct FQDN for my samba ADDC but somehow it can't connect to it.
```

I made certain that the 2 servers have a connection by pinging the windows server from my samba ADDC and pinging my samba ADDC from the windows server. both ping request go through with no problem.

I had this problem before with the windows server 2003-2008 servers, but that was because I needed to tell samba, that it had to act like a domain controller, but that is already set up, hence the reason I can join the windows server 2003-2008 to the domain, without any problems.

I also demoted the native domain controller running on windows server 2012, but that didn't work either.

on the linux end, I'm pretty sure I have set it up correctly, so the problem has to be somewhere in the newer windows server versions

if it could help, here's my smb.conf, from the ubuntu server:

```
[global]
    workgroup = MOSEK.INTRANET
    netbios name = FREDERICIA
    server string = MOSEK PDC

    deadtime = 10

    log level = 1
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 5000
    debug pid = yes
    debug uid = yes
    syslog = 0
    utmp = yes

    security = user
    domain logons = yes
    domain master = yes
    local master = yes
    preferred master = yes
    os level = 255
    logon path =
    logon home =
    logon drive = x:
    logon script = \\fredericia\logon\logon.bat
    acl allow execute always = True

    passdb backend = ldapsam:"ldap://fredericia.mosek.intranet/"
    ldap ssl = off
    ldap admin dn = cn=admin,dc=mosek,dc=intranet
    ldap delete dn = no

    ## Sync UNIX password with Samba password
    ## Method 1:
    ldap password sync = yes
    ## Method 2:
    ;ldap password sync = no
    ;unix password sync = yes
    ;passwd program = /usr/sbin/smbldap-passwd -u '%u'
    ;passwd chat = "Changing *\nNew password*" %n\n "*Retype new password*"$

    ldap suffix = dc=mosek,dc=intranet
    ldap user suffix = ou=Users
    ldap group suffix = ou=Groups
    ldap machine suffix = ou=Computers
    ldap idmap suffix = ou=Idmap

    add user script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-useradd -m '%u' -t 1
    rename user script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-usermod -r '%unew' '%uold'
    delete user script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-userdel '%u'
    set primary group script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-usermod -g '%g' '%u'
    add group script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-groupadd -p '%g'
    delete group script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-groupdel '%g'
    add user to group script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-groupmod -m '%u' '%g'
    delete user from group script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-groupmod -x '%u' '%g'
    add machine script = /usr/sbin/smbldap-useradd -w '%u' -t 1

[NETLOGON]
    path = /space/logon
    browseable = no
    share modes = no

[PROFILES]
    path = /var/lib/samba/profiles
    browseable = no
    writeable = yes
    create mask = 0611
    directory mask = 0700
    profile acls = yes
    csc policy = disable
    map system = yes
    map hidden = yes
```

also here's my ldap.conf:

```
###DEBCONF###
##
## Configuration of this file will be managed by debconf as long as the
## first line of the file says '###DEBCONF###'
##
## You should use dpkg-reconfigure to configure this file via debconf
##

#
# @(#)$Id: ldap.conf,v 1.38 2006/05/15 08:13:31 lukeh Exp $
#
# This is the configuration file for the LDAP nameservice
# switch library and the LDAP PAM module.
#
# PADL Software
# http://www.padl.com
#

# Your LDAP server. Must be resolvable without using LDAP.
# Multiple hosts may be specified, each separated by a
# space. How long nss_ldap takes to failover depends on
# whether your LDAP client library supports configurable
# network or connect timeouts (see bind_timelimit).
#host 127.0.0.1

# The distinguished name of the search base.
base dc=mosek,dc=intranet

# Another way to specify your LDAP server is to provide an
uri ldapi:///fredericia.mosek.intranet
# Unix Domain Sockets to connect to a local LDAP Server.
#uri ldap://127.0.0.1/
#uri ldaps://127.0.0.1/
#uri ldapi://%2fvar%2frun%2fldapi_sock/
# Note: %2f encodes the '/' used as directory separator

# The LDAP version to use (defaults to 3
# if supported by client library)
ldap_version 3

# The distinguished name to bind to the server with.
# Optional: default is to bind anonymously.
#binddn cn=proxyuser,dc=padl,dc=com

# The credentials to bind with.
# Optional: default is no credential.
#bindpw secret

# The distinguished name to bind to the server with
# if the effective user ID is root. Password is
# stored in /etc/ldap.secret (mode 600)
#rootbinddn cn=admin,dc=mosek,dc=intranet

# The port.
# Optional: default is 389.
#port 389
#scope sub
#scope one
#scope base

# Search timelimit
#timelimit 30

# Bind/connect timelimit
#bind_timelimit 30

# Reconnect policy: hard (default) will retry connecting to
# the software with exponential backoff, soft will fail
# immediately.
#bind_policy hard

# Idle timelimit; client will close connections
# (nss_ldap only) if the server has not been contacted
# for the number of seconds specified below.
#idle_timelimit 3600

# Filter to AND with uid=%s
#pam_filter objectclass=account

# The user ID attribute (defaults to uid)
#pam_login_attribute uid

# Search the root DSE for the password policy (works
# with Netscape Directory Server)
#pam_lookup_policy yes

# Check the 'host' attribute for access control
# Default is no; if set to yes, and user has no
# value for the host attribute, and pam_ldap is
# configured for account management (authorization)
# then the user will not be allowed to login.
#pam_check_host_attr yes

# Check the 'authorizedService' attribute for access
# control
# Default is no; if set to yes, and the user has no
# value for the authorizedService attribute, and
# pam_ldap is configured for account management
# (authorization) then the user will not be allowed
# to login.
#pam_check_service_attr yes

# Group to enforce membership of
#pam_groupdn cn=PAM,ou=Groups,dc=padl,dc=com

# Group member attribute
#pam_member_attribute uniquemember

# Specify a minium or maximum UID number allowed
#pam_min_uid 0
#pam_max_uid 0

# Template login attribute, default template user
# (can be overriden by value of former attribute
# in user's entry)
#pam_login_attribute userPrincipalName
#pam_template_login_attribute uid
#pam_template_login nobody

# HEADS UP: the pam_crypt, pam_nds_passwd,
# and pam_ad_passwd options are no
# longer supported.
#
# Do not hash the password at all; presume
# the directory server will do it, if
# necessary. This is the default.
pam_password md5

# Hash password locally; required for University of
# Michigan LDAP server, and works with Netscape
# Directory Server if you're using the UNIX-Crypt
# hash mechanism and not using the NT Synchronization
# service.
#pam_password crypt

# Remove old password first, then update in
# cleartext. Necessary for use with Novell
# Directory Services (NDS)
#pam_password clear_remove_old
#pam_password nds

# RACF is an alias for the above. For use with
#pam_password racf

# Update Active Directory password, by
# creating Unicode password and updating
# unicodePwd attribute.
#pam_password ad

# Use the OpenLDAP password change
# extended operation to update the password.
#pam_password exop

# Redirect users to a URL or somesuch on password
# changes.
#pam_password_prohibit_message Please visit http://internal to change your password.

# RFC2307bis naming contexts
# Syntax:
# nss_base_XXX          base?scope?filter
# where scope is {base,one,sub}
# and filter is a filter to be &'d with the
# default filter.
# You can omit the suffix eg:
# nss_base_passwd       ou=People,
# to append the default base DN but this
# may incur a small performance impact.
nss_base_passwd ou=People,dc=mosek,dc=intranet?one
nss_base_shadow ou=People,dc=mosek,dc=intranet?one
nss_base_group          ou=Group,dc=mosek,dc=intranet?one
#nss_base_hosts         ou=Hosts,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_services      ou=Services,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_networks      ou=Networks,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_protocols     ou=Protocols,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_rpc           ou=Rpc,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_ethers        ou=Ethers,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_netmasks      ou=Networks,dc=padl,dc=com?ne
#nss_base_bootparams    ou=Ethers,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_aliases       ou=Aliases,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_netgroup      ou=Netgroup,dc=padl,dc=com?one

# attribute/objectclass mapping
# Syntax:
#nss_map_attribute      rfc2307attribute        mapped_attribute
#nss_map_objectclass    rfc2307objectclass      mapped_objectclass

# configure --enable-nds is no longer supported.
# NDS mappings
#nss_map_attribute uniqueMember member

# Services for UNIX 3.5 mappings
#nss_map_objectclass posixAccount User
#nss_map_objectclass shadowAccount User
#nss_map_attribute uid msSFU30Name
#nss_map_attribute uniqueMember msSFU30PosixMember
#nss_map_attribute userPassword msSFU30Password
#nss_map_attribute homeDirectory msSFU30HomeDirectory
#nss_map_attribute homeDirectory msSFUHomeDirectory
#nss_map_objectclass posixGroup Group
#pam_login_attribute msSFU30Name
#pam_filter objectclass=User
#pam_password ad

# configure --enable-mssfu-schema is no longer supported.
# Services for UNIX 2.0 mappings
#nss_map_objectclass posixAccount User
#nss_map_objectclass shadowAccount user
#nss_map_attribute uid msSFUName
#nss_map_attribute uniqueMember posixMember
#nss_map_attribute userPassword msSFUPassword
#nss_map_attribute homeDirectory msSFUHomeDirectory
#nss_map_attribute shadowLastChange pwdLastSet
#nss_map_objectclass posixGroup Group
#nss_map_attribute cn msSFUName
#pam_login_attribute msSFUName
#pam_filter objectclass=User
#pam_password ad

# RFC 2307 (AD) mappings
#nss_map_objectclass posixAccount user
#nss_map_objectclass shadowAccount user
#nss_map_attribute uid sAMAccountName
#nss_map_attribute homeDirectory unixHomeDirectory
#nss_map_attribute shadowLastChange pwdLastSet
#nss_map_objectclass posixGroup group
#nss_map_attribute uniqueMember member
#pam_login_attribute sAMAccountName
#pam_filter objectclass=User
#pam_password ad

# configure --enable-authpassword is no longer supported
# AuthPassword mappings
#nss_map_attribute userPassword authPassword

# AIX SecureWay mappings
#nss_map_objectclass posixAccount aixAccount
#nss_base_passwd ou=aixaccount,?one
#nss_map_attribute uid userName
#nss_map_attribute gidNumber gid
#nss_map_attribute uidNumber uid
#nss_map_attribute userPassword passwordChar
#nss_map_objectclass posixGroup aixAccessGroup
#nss_base_group ou=aixgroup,?one
#nss_map_attribute cn groupName
#nss_map_attribute uniqueMember member
#pam_login_attribute userName
#pam_filter objectclass=aixAccount
#pam_password clear

# Netscape SDK LDAPS
#ssl on

# Netscape SDK SSL options
#sslpath /etc/ssl/certs

# OpenLDAP SSL mechanism
# start_tls mechanism uses the normal LDAP port, LDAPS typically 636
#ssl on

# OpenLDAP SSL options
# Require and verify server certificate (yes/no)
# Default is to use libldap's default behavior, which can be configured in
# /etc/openldap/ldap.conf using the TLS_REQCERT setting.  The default for
# OpenLDAP 2.0 and earlier is "no", for 2.1 and later is "yes".
#tls_checkpeer yes

# CA certificates for server certificate verification
# At least one of these are required if tls_checkpeer is "yes"
#tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/ca.cert
#tls_cacertdir /etc/ssl/certs

# Seed the PRNG if /dev/urandom is not provided
#tls_randfile /var/run/egd-pool

# SSL cipher suite
# See man ciphers for syntax
#tls_ciphers TLSv1

# Client certificate and key
# Use these, if your server requires client authentication.
#tls_cert
#tls_key

# Disable SASL security layers. This is needed for AD.
#sasl_secprops maxssf=0

# Override the default Kerberos ticket cache location.
#krb5_ccname FILE:/etc/.ldapcache

# SASL mechanism for PAM authentication - use is experimental
# at present and does not support password policy control
#pam_sasl_mech DIGEST-MD5
nss_initgroups_ignoreusers _apt,avahi,backup,bin,colord,daemon,ftp,games,gnats,irc,landscape,libuuid,list,lp,mail,man,messagebus,news,nslcd,ntp,openldap,proxy,root,sshd,statd,sync,sys,syslog,systemd-bus-proxy,sy$
```

Comment: I contacted Microsoft with the problem, and they stated that the newer windows systems (2012-present) uses WMI, which samba isn't compatible with as of yet, and that is why it's acting up. So the fix for the problem will hopefully come in later samba versions